# Calling Javascript method from SilverLight

Tags: c#, javascript, silverlight

Am using below line of code in silverlight project to call the javascript method named  'ExcelExport'

```
HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("ExcelExport", strData,"Invoices");
```

Its working well in the local host and IPAddress.
If I use machine name in the url getting error

> An unhandled exception ('Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application
>   Failed to Invoke: ExcelExport.   at
>   System.Windows.Browser.ScriptObject.Invoke(String name, Object[] args)

Can anyone help me to find the issue?